# I am looking for a flexible way to rotate a gameobject around another

Tags: unity, physics, rotate

I try to make an object rotate around another object on mouse input. In order to achieve this I used this code:

```
transform.RotateAround(objectToRotateAround.transform.position, Vector3.back, Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

I use GetAxisRaw because the movement has to be precise (the game that I am making requires a lot of reaction).

The problem is the shield movement doesn't feel good. I would like to be able to add a little bit of friction to the movement.

A solution that would enable me to tweak certain aspects of the rotation would be ideal. Any kind of guidance or documentation that might help is also very well-received .

PS: I also tried to work with Quaternions. This was the code that I've tried.

```
 Vector3 relativePos = objectToRotateAround.transform.position - transform.position;
 transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos,Vector3.forward), Time.deltaTime);
 transform.Translate(0, 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

There are a few problems with this code.

The Quaternion.LookRotation rotates my object on all 3 axes instead of the Y-axis.
I think even if the object rotates properly, the Translate method will make it move the same as the previous solution.
Thank you for your time and attention. I really appreciate it.

Comment: have you tried manipulating the `speed` variable in the original rotation? Whatever effect you want to add to the rotatation it'll have to manipulate the value of `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed`. Try multiplying it by `Mathf.sin(Time.time) //note: not deltatime `, it will feel even worse but it might give you an idea about how to implement "friction" (not sure what you have in mind).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This gave me an idea. I used a parabola function and I passed in as an argument the GetAxis value. It basically does the same thing but now I can control the speed(acceleration) behavior via some parameters of the parabola generating function.